# CSS animated DIV as background with transparent BG Div with content on top

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've been trying to place some bootstrap/html/css on top of CSS animated starfield as a background.

One way that seems to stick out online is to make a 1x1 pixel png. I'm hoping there is a way to code in transparency instead.

background: rgba - to play with alpha doesn't work.
opacity:0 also doesn't work.
z-index:-1 with the above also doesn't work.

I've been fiddling with it for a while. Here is the codepen.
http://s.codepen.io/awaybackhome/debug/QdqNNX

Ideally, I'd like to see the stars coming through the Div that contains text, the Div(column) left of the quote box, and the Div that contains the buttons. Instead, I'm just getting the black background.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience this is fairly simple code, but a bit twisted initially. Start with a `<div>` for the background. Give it an `id` or `class` relating to position on top of the Star Field background. Now, in your CSS reference the new `<div>` by setting `background-color: transparent;`. This makes it effectively an invisible layer you can output on top of. Next, put your stuff inside the new `<div>` layer. HTML should look similar to this:

```
 <div id="starFieldBackground">
     <div id="background">
         <p>Your Code Here</p>
     </div>
 </div>
```

And your CSS:

```
 #background {
     background-color:transparent;
 }
```

Be sure to set the `width` and `height` of `<div id="background">`.
This could also be accomplished with `z-index` positioning with a bit more code.

Edit:
reference to `background-color` properties.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-color.asp

Comment: I gave it a shot but doesn't seem to do the trick. I also tried putting the transparent onto each starfield div. Then I tried to put it on a Div on top of the Starfields. I then changed the Div to a simple h1 tag to see if it'd show through.